# Why do sshfs and fuse create thousands of file descriptors (unbounded growth) for a Java process?

Tags: linux, debian, java, sshfs, fuse

I'm trying to understand why I see thousands and thousands of new file descriptors such as the following in `/proc/PID/fd` directory of a `java` process:

```
$ sudo ls -lt /proc/585/fd | head
total 0
lr-x------ 1 crate crate 64 Jan 14 09:45 3036 -> /sys/fs/cgroup
lr-x------ 1 crate crate 64 Jan 14 09:45 3037 -> /sys/fs/cgroup/sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
lr-x------ 1 crate crate 64 Jan 14 09:45 3038 -> /sys/fs/cgroup/sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
lr-x------ 1 crate crate 64 Jan 14 09:45 3035 -> /sys/fs/cgroup
lr-x------ 1 crate crate 64 Jan 14 09:45 3032 -> /sys/fs/cgroup
lr-x------ 1 crate crate 64 Jan 14 09:45 3033 -> /sys/fs/cgroup/sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
lr-x------ 1 crate crate 64 Jan 14 09:45 3034 -> /sys/fs/cgroup/sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
lr-x------ 1 crate crate 64 Jan 14 09:45 3028 -> /sys/fs/cgroup
lr-x------ 1 crate crate 64 Jan 14 09:45 3029 -> /sys/fs/cgroup/sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
```

This is from a Debian GNU/Linux server (version 11.1). This machine is used as one of the nodes of a distributed database ([CrateDB](https://crate.io/), version [4.6.6](https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/4.6/appendices/release-notes/4.6.6.html),  programmed in Java).

Recently, I've installed `sshfs` on that machine:

```
$ dpkg -l | egrep "(fuse)|(sshf)"
ii  fuse3                      3.10.3-2                       amd64        Filesystem in Userspace (3.x version)
ii  libfuse2:amd64             2.9.9-5                        amd64        Filesystem in Userspace (library)
ii  libfuse3-3:amd64           3.10.3-2                       amd64        Filesystem in Userspace (library) (3.x version)
ii  sshfs                      3.7.1+repack-2                 amd64        filesystem client based on SSH File Transfer Protocol
```

But I never used or configured `sshfs` after installing the package. In other words, I didn't create a mount via `sshfs` to another server, etc.

Currently `/etc/mtab` on that server is:

```
$ cat /etc/mtab | column -t
sysfs       /sys                      sysfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime                                                      0  0
proc        /proc                     proc        rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime                                                      0  0
udev        /dev                      devtmpfs    rw,nosuid,relatime,size=32885744k,nr_inodes=8221436,mode=755                         0  0
devpts      /dev/pts                  devpts      rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000                                0  0
tmpfs       /run                      tmpfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=6580424k,mode=755                               0  0
/dev/sda1   /                         ext4        rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,stripe=256                                             0  0
securityfs  /sys/kernel/security      securityfs  rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime                                                      0  0
tmpfs       /dev/shm                  tmpfs       rw,nosuid,nodev                                                                      0  0
tmpfs       /run/lock                 tmpfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k                                           0  0
cgroup2     /sys/fs/cgroup            cgroup2     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot                      0  0
pstore      /sys/fs/pstore            pstore      rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime                                                      0  0
none        /sys/fs/bpf               bpf         rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700                                             0  0
systemd-1   /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc  autofs      rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=30739       0  0
mqueue      /dev/mqueue               mqueue      rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime                                                      0  0
tracefs     /sys/kernel/tracing       tracefs     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime                                                      0  0
debugfs     /sys/kernel/debug         debugfs     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime                                                      0  0
fusectl     /sys/fs/fuse/connections  fusectl     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime                                                      0  0
hugetlbfs   /dev/hugepages            hugetlbfs   rw,relatime,pagesize=2M                                                              0  0
configfs    /sys/kernel/config        configfs    rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime                                                      0  0
/dev/sdb1   /data                     ext4        rw,relatime,stripe=256                                                               0  0
tmpfs       /run/user/1000            tmpfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=6580420k,nr_inodes=1645105,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000  0  0
```

Few days after that, I've encountered "Too many files open" from the web UI of the CrateDB system.

Eventually, I **rebooted** that server, and then started to monitor it carefully.

Now, when I check the processes with the most number of file descriptors, I see that it is the `java` process:

```
$ sudo lsof +c 0 | awk '{ print $2 " " $1; }' | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n5 | column -t
360126  585   java
136     558   rsyslogd
96      472   systemd-timesyn
87      1     systemd
61      3106  sshd
```

When I visit the `fd` directory for PID of `585` (`java`), I see the most recently created file descriptors as:

```
lr-x------ 1 crate crate 64 Jan 14 09:45 3036 -> /sys/fs/cgroup
lr-x------ 1 crate crate 64 Jan 14 09:45 3037 -> /sys/fs/cgroup/sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
lr-x------ 1 crate crate 64 Jan 14 09:45 3038 -> /sys/fs/cgroup/sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
lr-x------ 1 crate crate 64 Jan 14 09:45 3035 -> /sys/fs/cgroup
lr-x------ 1 crate crate 64 Jan 14 09:45 3032 -> /sys/fs/cgroup
```

When I count the number of file descriptors related to `cgroup` or `fuse`, I see thousands of them:

```
$ sudo ls -l /proc/585/fd | egrep "(cgroup)|(fuse)" | wc -l
2752
```

I also observe the **number of file descriptors** for that `java` (CrateDB) process starts to **increase** when I interact with the web-based administrative UI of CrateDB.

The **number of file descriptors** related to `cgroup` and `sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount` continues to increases.

I'm trying to understand this **unbounded growth** in the number of **file descriptors** related to `cgroup` and `sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount` for a Java process.

Extra information: I have another set of servers running the exact same Java application (CrateDB) on Debian GNU/Linux (version 10.x), and they don't have `sshfs` installed as the major difference. When I monitor the file descriptors in `fd` directory of the Java process there, I don't see any `cgroup` and `sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount` related file descriptors there, and I never had "Too many files open" issues there.

I somehow suspect that this issue isn't caused directly by CrateDB, but rather (maybe indirectly?) by `sshfs` and `fuse`, therefore my question is: how can I test this?

**UPDATE** (2022-02-17): I tested the following on a new Debian GNU/Linux 11.2 virtual machine:

**Step 1:** Install latest stable version (4.7.0) of CrateDB via `apt`. The Java virtual machine used by CrateDB is reported as the following:

```
$ /usr/share/crate/jdk/bin/java --version
openjdk 17.0.1 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.1+12 (build 17.0.1+12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.1+12 (build 17.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**Step 2:** List the processes with most number of open files:

```
echo -e "cntFiles PID Process Name" && echo "========================" && sudo lsof -e /run/user/1000/gvfs +c 0 | awk '{ print $2 " " $1; }' | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n5

cntFiles PID Process Name    
========================
   7439 484 java
   6876 1493 gnome-shell
   1776 1799 gsd-xsettings
   1566 1620 evolution-alarm
   1463 1817 ibus-x11
```

Then start the `strace` for `java` process and focus on what the `java` process and all its threads to with regards to `/sys/fs/cgroup`:

```
 $ sudo strace --decode-fds=all --trace-path=/sys/fs/cgroup --follow-forks --attach 484
strace: Process 484 attached with 37 threads
```

At this stage, `strace` doesn't print anything.

**Step 3**: Run Firefox and **view CrateDB administrative web UI** at http://localhost:4200/#!/

As soon as I visit the web admin UI of CrateDB, `strace` starts to **report a lot**!

```
$ sudo strace --decode-fds=all --trace-path=/sys/fs/cgroup --follow-forks --attach 484
strace: Process 484 attached with 37 threads
strace: Process 2697 attached
strace: Process 2698 attached
strace: Process 2699 attached
strace: Process 2700 attached
[pid  2698] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0xc} ---
strace: Process 2701 attached
[pid  1325] lstat("/sys/fs/cgroup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  1325] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/fs/cgroup", O_RDONLY) = 151</sys/fs/cgroup>
[pid  1325] dup(151</sys/fs/cgroup>)    = 152</sys/fs/cgroup>
[pid  1325] fstat(151</sys/fs/cgroup>, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  1325] fcntl(151</sys/fs/cgroup>, F_GETFL) = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
[pid  1325] fcntl(151</sys/fs/cgroup>, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
[pid  1325] getdents64(151</sys/fs/cgroup>, 0x7f6e9c01bc90 /* 29 entries */, 32768) = 1112
[pid  2400] lstat("/sys/fs/cgroup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  2400] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/fs/cgroup", O_RDONLY) = 155</sys/fs/cgroup>
[pid  2400] dup(155</sys/fs/cgroup>)    = 156</sys/fs/cgroup>
[pid  2400] fstat(155</sys/fs/cgroup>, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  2400] fcntl(155</sys/fs/cgroup>, F_GETFL) = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
[pid  2400] fcntl(155</sys/fs/cgroup>, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
[pid  2400] getdents64(155</sys/fs/cgroup>, 0x7f6ec09507d0 /* 29 entries */, 32768) = 1112
[pid  1325] lstat("/sys/fs/cgroup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  1325] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/fs/cgroup", O_RDONLY) = 159</sys/fs/cgroup>
[pid  1325] dup(159</sys/fs/cgroup>)    = 162</sys/fs/cgroup>
[pid  1325] fstat(159</sys/fs/cgroup>, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  1325] fcntl(159</sys/fs/cgroup>, F_GETFL) = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
[pid  1325] fcntl(159</sys/fs/cgroup>, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
[pid  1325] getdents64(159</sys/fs/cgroup>, 0x7f6e9c02bd10 /* 29 entries */, 32768) = 1112
[pid  2400] lstat("/sys/fs/cgroup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  2400] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/fs/cgroup", O_RDONLY) = 163</sys/fs/cgroup>
[pid  2400] dup(163</sys/fs/cgroup>)    = 164</sys/fs/cgroup>
[pid  2400] fstat(163</sys/fs/cgroup>, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  2400] fcntl(163</sys/fs/cgroup>, F_GETFL) = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
[pid  2400] fcntl(163</sys/fs/cgroup>, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
[pid  2400] getdents64(163</sys/fs/cgroup>, 0x7f6ec0dd90e0 /* 29 entries */, 32768) = 1112
[pid  1325] lstat("/sys/fs/cgroup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  1325] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/fs/cgroup", O_RDONLY) = 167</sys/fs/cgroup>
[pid  1325] dup(167</sys/fs/cgroup>)    = 168</sys/fs/cgroup>
[pid  1325] fstat(167</sys/fs/cgroup>, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  1325] fcntl(167</sys/fs/cgroup>, F_GETFL) = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
[pid  1325] fcntl(167</sys/fs/cgroup>, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
[pid  1325] getdents64(167</sys/fs/cgroup>, 0x7f6e9c03bd90 /* 29 entries */, 32768) = 1112
[pid  2400] lstat("/sys/fs/cgroup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  2400] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/fs/cgroup", O_RDONLY) = 171</sys/fs/cgroup>
[pid  2400] dup(171</sys/fs/cgroup>)    = 172</sys/fs/cgroup>
[pid  2400] fstat(171</sys/fs/cgroup>, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  2400] fcntl(171</sys/fs/cgroup>, F_GETFL) = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
[pid  2400] fcntl(171</sys/fs/cgroup>, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
[pid  2400] getdents64(171</sys/fs/cgroup>, 0x7f6ec06baa20 /* 29 entries */, 32768) = 1112
[pid  1325] lstat("/sys/fs/cgroup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  1325] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/fs/cgroup", O_RDONLY) = 175</sys/fs/cgroup>
[pid  1325] dup(175</sys/fs/cgroup>)    = 176</sys/fs/cgroup>
[pid  1325] fstat(175</sys/fs/cgroup>, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  1325] fcntl(175</sys/fs/cgroup>, F_GETFL) = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
[pid  1325] fcntl(175</sys/fs/cgroup>, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
[pid  1325] getdents64(175</sys/fs/cgroup>, 0x7f6e9c04be10 /* 29 entries */, 32768) = 1112
[pid  2400] lstat("/sys/fs/cgroup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  2400] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/fs/cgroup", O_RDONLY) = 179</sys/fs/cgroup>
[pid  2400] dup(179</sys/fs/cgroup>)    = 180</sys/fs/cgroup>
[pid  2400] fstat(179</sys/fs/cgroup>, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  2400] fcntl(179</sys/fs/cgroup>, F_GETFL) = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
[pid  2400] fcntl(179</sys/fs/cgroup>, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
[pid  2400] getdents64(179</sys/fs/cgroup>, 0x7f6ec15347f0 /* 29 entries */, 32768) = 1112
strace: Process 2738 attached
[pid  2738] +++ exited with 0 +++
strace: Process 2739 attached
[pid  2739] +++ exited with 0 +++
```

**Step 4**: I exit Firefox, no more interaction with the web admin UI of CrateDB and immediately `strace` stops reporting anything with respect to `/sys/fs/cgroup`.

**Step 5**: I check the number of open files for `java` process and now that number is 8778. If I continue to use the web admin UI, that number grows unbounded.

Comment: Apart from the administration, what else is using the DB?  Version of CrateDB might also be useful.  Containers involved?  VMs?

Comment: Hello Gerard, I've modified the post and added that it is version 4.6.6 of CrateDB. There are no containers involved: installed Debian on the servers, and then CrateDB, running as a stand-alone Java application. This is a cluster recently created for development/testing purposes, there's almost nothing using it (except for occassional connections via web browser and PostgreSQL's psql utility).

Comment: Are you sure about the "occasional" connections?  There's no public access possible?  Can you verify with netstat how many connections are open on that systep?

Comment: Hello Gerard, this 3-node cluster is located in an internal network of an on-premise data center, with no public access. I've monitored it with `ss -s` and `ss -lp` for a while, the number of connections increase when I connect to the Java-based databases web UI, and when I exit web browser, number of connections go down, as expected.

Comment: And in the meantime, the number of `cgroup` and `fuse` related file descriptors continue to increase as I use the web UI, which in turn, runs some SQL queries to show some stats for the database cluster.

Comment: There is no way either sshfs or FUSE could be causing this. In the first place, it’s not even interacting with these two but rather the Control Groups tree. You should contact the creators of CrateDB, because it is most likely to “blame”.

Comment: I've installed a single node.  The admin pages and a python client don't reproduce your problem.  Is there anything in your control groups that would matter to CrateDB?

Comment: Even with two nodes, not a single reference to sys or cgroups in /proc/*/fd

Comment: Gerard, thanks for further comments. I wonder a) if your system is also Debian 11 "bullseye", b) if you also installed `sshfs` packages via `apt get` on those two nodes? (Because only after `sshfs` package installation I started to encounter this weird situation). As a last resort, I'll try to see if I can find more on my system by using `strace`.

Comment: @EmreSevinç,  you should have given me a heads up!  I'm on Devuan Chimaera (bullseye spinoff), but with homebrewn kernel - contains only what I need. Yes to apt-get.  My question on control groups?  Tot wederhoren!

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, I was able to replicate the issue I'm experiencing on a single Debian 11.2 virtual machine. See UPDATE (2022-02-17) at the end of the original post above.

Comment: Was the original problem also in a VM or container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the issue was **not related** to `sshfs` or `fuse`, but rather about the interaction of CrateDB (coded in Java) and GNU/Linux distributions using **cgroup v2**, as [identified by the CrateDB team](https://community.crate.io/t/what-to-do-to-fix-too-many-open-files-on-a-3-node-cluster-with-almost-no-data/981/29) :

> We came across this issue again and could finally point it down to a
> bug in CrateDB in combination with distributions using cgroup v2. The
> fix is already merged and has been released to the testings channels
> with version 4.8.4. I expect a 5.0.2 soon to follow.

For more details, please see:

- https://github.com/crate/crate/issues/13027
- https://community.crate.io/t/what-to-do-to-fix-too-many-open-files-on-a-3-node-cluster-with-almost-no-data/981